# change environment variable for all processes in the same machine with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried to run multiple processes on 1 instance in AWS EC2 and set environment variables for all of them by adding a new variable in the first run.

The first process set a new environment variable by the following line in python:

```
os.environ["access_token"] = "token"
```

and when the next process run I got:

```
print("access_token" in os.environ)
-> False
```

How can I set a global environment variable in the first run and use it in the next processes?

I need a different variable for each instance so I can't add a global environment variable for all instances before the first run

Comment: There's no such thing as a system-global environment variable. They're all process-local, and inherited from the process that starts them (not some random process that ran before them in time, but specifically the _parent process_, the process from which the child is spawned).

Comment: What do you mean by "first run" -- how are these processes 'run'? And what do you mean by "add a global environment variable for all instances" -- instances of what?

Comment: This would be better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow, as it's at its core a system administration question, and a better understanding of how your operating system is designed would moot it.

Comment: (if this is a Linux distro using systemd, one approach you might take is to have one service that creates a file that other services use as an `EnvironmentFile`, and set up dependencies between the services so the ones that need the environment variable don't run until the one that creates it is complete).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this work (without involving your process supervisor), you need to make your first process **directly start** the second process itself; this can be repeated for as many processes as need be, invoking them all through the same wrapper.

Let's say you have a service definition like so:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/set-my-environment-variable
ExecStart=/usr/bin/service-that-needs-environment-variable
```

As you've noticed, this doesn't work: The environment variables that `set-my-environment-variable` sets are all gone when it exits, so `service-that-needs-environment-variable` can't see them.

One thing you can try that **does** work is the following:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/set-my-environment-variable /usr/bin/service-that-needs-environment-variable
```

...if you change `set-my-environment-variable` to be like the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

os.environ["access_token"] = "token"
os.execv(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:])
```